# Bootstrap responsive div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi everyone i am facing a problem with bootstrap and a div element that make weird behaviour once in larger screens.
Here is the goal result i want to achieve : 
[image]

And here is the result i get when i make the screen bigger :
[image]

And finally here is my bootstrap code:
[image]

If someone can figure it out why i get such weird behaviour i would take for sure the explanation. Thanks in advance the final result i am trying to achieve is the following one :
[image]

Comment: Try including `col-lg` classes in the code once.

Comment: Rather than posting images of code, you should post the code directly

Comment: i replaced the "visible-md" i had with "hidden-xs hidden-sm" and it works the "visible-lg" attribute doesn't work thanks for help. If you have any more advice on how to fulfill this bootstrap design i would be greatfull!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bootstrap grid system offers you to use multiple grid options to different screen sizes,

Use the `col-lg-*` for bigger screens and it will work for you.

> You can read more about the [bootstrap grid system](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp)